# Translate a rectangle for a Scene using a Timer in JavaFX

Tags: java, timer, javafx, translate, scene

I have a rectangle in a Scene that I want to translate on a linear path in JavaFX using a timer. For every mSecs milliseconds, I want the rectangle to translate d distance, along an xy plane in JavaFX. I know how to simply translate something using rec.setX(x) and rec.setY(y), and having it move around. I don't want to use animations or any complicated class, I just want a timer to start, and every time it ticks a certain increment, I want to translate that rectangle a certain amount. Simple, basic animation like a flipbook. Could anyone help and/or refer me to a proper class API?

Comment: Why not just use a TranslateTransition? That's exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: Note sure why you want to avoid animations. Note that animation APIs are designed so that they drop frames when your system is under a load, instead of slowing down your animation. Most of the time, you want framedropping. An exception is when programming a simulation, in which case you cannot afford to skip a simulation step.

Comment: I want a rectangle that I can translate to a certain position. The first phase was figuring out how to translate it, the second phase is learning how to translate it to a certain position.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Rectangle on the Scene. Calculate dx and dy depending on your start and end point, or in your case depending on d and the angle. Use an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) as your (game) loop. Increment x and y by dx and dy in every animation frame until the Rectangle reaches the destination.